# How to detect if Android Auto is starting, so I can set the initial PlaybackState?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-auto

According to the [*Android app quality for cars*](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/car-app-quality) guideline MA-1:

> [Media apps must not autoplay on startup or without user initiated action to select the app or app media.](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/car-app-quality#media-autoplay).

The guidelines suggest reading [Implement play commands](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media#playback-commands) which refers to instructions to [Set initial PlaybackState](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media#initial-playback-state). This states:

> Your app should not automatically start playing music when Android Automotive OS or Android Auto connect to your media browser service.

This seems clear - when starting Android Auto, music should not auto play.

However, I can't see an obvious way that you can detect *when* Android Auto starts and connects to the app.

My media app has functionality that auto plays when you use it on a mobile phone and it was last left in a "playing" state. So I need to disable this when Android Auto connects.

When Android Auto does connect, `MediaSessionCompat.Callback:onPlay` is invoked. However, the same callback to `onPlay` is made if the user clicks the "Play" icon. Obviously, if a user clicks the Play icon, the music should play.

So how do I know if the user has manually pressed play, or Android Auto has connected to the app?

Comment: As an aside, I found a place that might lead to music being started automatically. In the Android Auto UI, Settings > Start-up Mode there's a "Start music automatically" setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in `MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback()`. You most likely have a media browser service set up for your Android Auto implementation. It has an `onConnected()` method specifically for this purpose, and you can use it to process any logic whenever your app initiates that connection

Comment: Thanks - this does appear to get called. I actually didn't have a `MediaBrowserCompat` instance already, but I created one inside my implementation of `MediaBrowserServiceCompat.onCreate()` - hopefully that's the right place.